# How do we enable smart contracts on UTXO based chains?

Tags: contract-design, evm

Smart contracts fundamentally enable change of state programmatically. (Is that a fair  fundamental description?).

How would one go about enabling smart contracts on UTXO based blockchain as against an account model?

Comment: There're serveral approaches for example Qtum https://medium.com/on-the-origin-of-smart-contract-platforms/on-the-origin-of-qtum-5f2e6daf798a

Answer (score 1):

Here's details of Komodo's upcoming UTXO based smart contracts system built on the draft IETF open standard, Crypto Conditions.

https://komodoplatform.com/crypto-conditions-utxo-based-smart-contracts/

Basically everything is derived from UTXOs and transactions move the state of the contract.

Disclaimer: I contribute to the Komodo project.  Some extra things, https://blog.komodoplatform.com/pre-alpha-komodo-utxo-smart-contracts-notes-7c5e8f49206 more coming.

Comment: Can you add more details of the solution? So in the future if the server is down or the page moved then the answer can still be useful.